# Syntax to calculate sum with maxima or wxmaxima using different variables

Tags: functions, maxima-software

So I'm not sure if I'm right here but I can try:

So we are having a statistics class at uni. The question is:

$x_{1}= 5$, $x_{2}= 3$, $x_{3}= 7$

$y_{1}= 6$, $y_{2}= 4$, $y_{3}= 12$

Calculate following:

$\sum_{i=2}^{3}(x_{i}+y_{i}) =$

I know it's actually quit trivial to calculate this by hand but I would really like to know how I can calculate such stuff using wxmaxima.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Give a man a fish)

```
x:[5,3,7]; 
y:[6,4,12]; 
sum(x[i]+y[i], i, 2, 3);
```

(Teach a man to fish ;)

At the wxmaxima command line, type `describe(sum)` or `example(sum)`

(The parenthetical remarks refer to an old saying, my favorite version of which is, "Build a man a fire and he'll be warm for a night.  Set a man on fire and he'll be warm for the rest of his life.")

Comment: Cool, thanks alot!
I just couldn't figure out how to save the values.
(x:[5,3,7];)
Did figure out this part though: sum(x[i]+y[i], i, 2, 3); but wasn't sure it was right.

Trust me,I was fishing for 3h but didn't catch anything! ;)

Comment: Glad I could help.  Yeah, some things in maxima are a little weird.  It's the only language I've used that defines variables using colons, like x:1.